# Using ProgressBar to Display Value Instead of Bar

Tags: python, progress-bar

Part of my python program is to load the contents of a (csv) file into a list. Since this file is large, I'd like to add some progress data about it. This is what I'm doing right now:

```
def loadFile(infilepath):
    answer = []
    with open(infilepath) as infile:
        for progress,row in enumerate(csv.reader(infile), 1):
            if not progress%10000:
                progress = format(progress, ',')
                print(progress, '\b'*len(progress), sep='', end='', flush=True)
            answer.append(doStuffWith(row))
    return answer

print("Loading Data... ", end='', flush=True)
data = loadData('path/to/file')
```

Normally, I'd replace the `print(progress, '\b'*len(progress), ...)` with `print(progress, '\r', ...)` to bring the cursor back to the start of the line. But that's not an option here, as the start of line is offset by `"Loading Data... "`. I was told that I could use [progressbar2](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/progressbar2) for this, but I can't seem to figure out how to make it write actual values, instead of a progress bar.

I'd appreciate any help on this

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom widget:

```
import time
from progressbar import ProgressBar, FormatLabel, UnknownLength

def transform(n):
    return format(n, ',')

widget = FormatLabel('Loading Data... %(value)s')
widget.mapping = {**widget.mapping, 'value': ('value', transform)}
with ProgressBar(widgets=[widget], max_value=UnknownLength) as bar:
    for i in range(1, 1234):
        time.sleep(0.001)
        bar.update(i)
```

Comment: I can't have `'Loading Data... '` as part of the the update message

Comment: Why not?  What difference does it make whether this is part of the progress bar context or not?

Comment: It would require too much refactoring. `Loading Data... ` isn't always the same - different functions that call this function print different string beforehand... and too many functions call this for me to refactor the function to take an extra parameter - I'd like to avoid that

Comment: Also, your solution doesn't work, as it doesn't update progress based on the input file, which has an unknown number of lines (usually much greater than 100). So `bar.update(lineNumber)` is a `ValueError`

Comment: Then you can't use \r, you have to keep track of the offset position of the start of line somehow.  Either with your own idea (a bunch of \b characters) or learn [curses](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/curses.html).

Comment: Could you provide an example of how to do this with curses?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget  I refuse to believe you read the contents of the curses link in the ~1 minute between me posting it and you replying.  Why don't you try it yourself first, and if you haven't figured it out yet you can ask again after attempting.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget *which has an unknown number of lines*  <--  I've updated the code for working with unknown length inputs.

Comment: `I've updated the code` <- doesn't work when I format `progress` as shown in my question. `TypeError: unorderable types: str() > int()` (and yes, I did change to `"%(value)s"`). `bar.update` doesn't automatically format `progress` when supplied as an `int`

Comment: @inspectorG4dget  you want comma separated 1000's ?

Comment: Yes. This is in my OP